# The elements of $X/\sim$, being a subset of $X$, are all the same cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let be $X$ a set and $\sim$ and an equivalence relation on $X$. True or
>   False. The elements of $X/\sim$, being a subset of $X$, are all the same
>   cardinality.

I don't see how I could verify or contradict this "conjecture". Is anyone is able to give me a hint to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: All you need to disprove it is a single counterexample. Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$, and define an equivalence relation on $X$ that has exactly two equivalence classes.

Comment: Ok, I think the relation $x \sim y$ equivalente to $ x \equiv y \pmod 2$ is a good one.

Comment: @J.G: Yes, that will work fine. Or you can simply define an equivalence relation by brute force, specifying which ordered pairs belong to it.

Comment: What kind of example do you suggest?

Comment: @J.G: As I said, yours works fine. But you could also let $$\sim\;=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle, \langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle\}\;,$$ for instance, with equivalence classes $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2\}$.

Comment: What is $<i,j>$ here? A vector?

Comment: @J.G: An ordered pair. You’re probably more used to writing $(i,j)$.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalence relation on a set $X$ determines a partition on $X$ via the equivalence classes.

Conversely, any partition on $X$ induces an equivalence relation: define $x$ to be in relation with $y$ if (and only if) $x$ and $y$ belong to the same element of the partition. The set of the equivalence classes is the same as the partition we started with.

This means that the equivalence classes can have no restrictions other than being non empty and pairwise disjoint, with their union being the whole set.

To see an explicit example, consider the partition $\bigl\{\{0,2\},\{1\}\bigr\}$ of $\{0,1,2\}$. This ends the counterexample to the statement that all equivalence classes share the same cardinality.

The equivalence relation can be written down in terms of ordered pairs like
$$
\{(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(1,1)\}
$$
but it's not really necessary.